# how to detect location in android very fastly

Tags: android, gps, location

my android application can detect longitude and latitude. but it take some time. my app has 9 activates and last activity should send location to data base. any one can give a solution for this. i want to detect location soon as possible, what did missed in my code?

```
package com.example.zlocation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    protected TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected String latitude,longitude; 
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html
use Fused location provider. for more info http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Try to use Last Location until updated location not came.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the location from gps provider.The problem with gps is however vit is accurate but it takes time in starting the gps and providing a location it can take anything from 2-30 seconds to provide the location if you want location as soon as possible have a look at fused location provider by google and implement it in that you can define the time after you want the location updates or from my personal experience i would suggest you to have a look at littlefluffy location library it is easier to implement.